# Why is the Dataset Designer throwing out of memory exceptions when saving

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5, exception, strongly-typed-dataset

So I have a strongly typed dataset design that has become pretty large compared to where it started.  Every so often, when I save the dataset it throws an out of memory exception.  If I exit out immediately and go back in, change a random item in the dataset to make it regenerate and switch it back, it saves and corrects everything...

If I don't and try to save again, now I have to modify the csproj file and spend a few minutes readjusting the environment because it doesn't know the dataset exists anymore and the entire solution becomes a list of errors.

Why does this keep happening?!  Its become a small annoyance for me but the person who is taking over this position when I leave will totally be blindsided by this.  It only happens when I try to save the xsd after making changes, and its pretty random when it happens.  Anybody have some good advise?

** NOTE **
This problem is being deleted since I left my job at the company where this was happening.  I don't have this issue on my own PC and Laptop so I cannot reproduce/solve this problem.

Please close this topic!

Answer (score 0):

This problem also happens to me and like you said completely random. I have found that cleaning the solution then deleting the "Bin" and "obj" folders and rebuilding the solution corrects the issue. Sometimes I have to delete and rebuild a couple times for it to work, very stange I know. If you do not see the "Bin" and "obj" folders, click the "Show All Files" icon at the top of the Solution Explorer. Hopefully there is a better solution to this issue than what I have suggested but it does work for me and I hope it does for you as well. Please mark as answered if this resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing the size of your windows Virtual Memory Paging file?

(Windows XP)  My Computer->Properties->Advanced->(Performance) Settings->Advanced->(Virtual Memory) Change.

With the amount of data you are working with, you might just be out of memory.  Increasing the page file size will prevent that problem, if you are unable to just add memory modules.